# Retrofit POST request response.isSuccessful() returning false

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am trying to make `POST` request using Retrofit2. But I am in a situation where the `response.isSuccessful()` is returning false and I do not know how to debug it. I checked my backend's logs and there are no errors, nothing.

I made sure that the request's URL is correct, also that all the parameters are right. What I am doing wrong? For me it seems that the request even doesn't make it to my server.

This is what I do:

I have class User with getters and setters:

```
public class User {
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    @Expose
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    @Expose
    private String firstName;
    @SerializedName("last_name")
    @Expose
    private String lastName;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

And I have my service:

```
public interface APIService {

    @POST("auth/register")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<User> register(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);
}
```

Now I try to execute it, which returns false in response block:

```
private void registerUser(){
        Call<User> registerCall = apiService.register(email, password);

        registerCall.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {

                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    int id = response.body().getId();
                    String firstName = response.body().getFirstName();
                    String lastName = response.body().getLastName();

                }else{
                    System.out.println("ERROR "+response.raw().body());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Edit: This is the ApiUtils:

```
public class ApiUtils {

    private ApiUtils() {}

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.mydomain.com/";

    public static APIService getAPIService() {

        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(APIService.class);
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong? How I can do more debugging? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what value of **apiService** please post full code

Comment: @ArpitPrajapati **apiService's** value is `ApiUtils.getAPIService();`

Comment: In **APIService** interface you add  **ResObject** try to replace it with **User** Class

Comment: @ArpitPrajapati oops, that is a typo, it is actually User in my code.

Comment: your code seems fine, check your @SerializedName's with your json data, which you are getting from api

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be problem with building retrofit instance(your getApiService method), and to see the log and status of api calls you can use http logging interceptor as:

```
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.interceptors().add(new LogJsonInterceptor());

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

you can see the raw JSON response of API using interceptor. Hope this may solve your problem.

Comment: The `interceptors` is not public so you can't access it outside of the package.