# The Data with user_id parameter doesn't show on the recylerView

Tags: java, rest, android-studio, retrofit2

The problem is about the data with `user_id` parameter doesn't show on the recylerView. I tried with many variant method such as to changes `user_id` to `session_id` as parameter but it still doesn't works. I'm building this application with method POST,GET,ect with using retrofit2.

This is the json when i executed on postman Tool "after success login":

http://localhost/web/api/transaction/findAll

```
{
    //"session_id": "93enj0lcs4catvps6ars7u1rlba8vvig",
    "user_id":74,
    "success": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "232",
            "user_id": "74",
            "item_code": "B002",
            "qty": "2",
            "price": "150",
            "total_price": "300"
        },
        {
            "id": "233",
            "user_id": "74",
            "item_code": "B002",
            "qty": "2",
            "price": "150",
            "total_price": "300"
        }
    ]
}
```

This a part code of activity_transaction:

```
     @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_transaction);
                    this.setTitle("INVOICE TRANSACTION");
                    session = new SessionManagement(getApplicationContext());


             HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
                final String userid       = user.get(SessionManagement.KEY_USERID);
                final String sessionid    = user.get(SessionManagement.KEY_SESSIONID);

                txt_userid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_userid);
                txt_userid.setText(userid);


                txtsession_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtsession_id);
                txtsession_id.setText(sessionid);

                final String user_id     = txt_userid.getText().toString();
                final String session_id  = txtsession_id.getText().toString();


                recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
                mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mManager);
                adapter = new TransactionAdapter(transactionList, getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                TransactionService transactionService = APIClient.getClient().create(TransactionService.class);
               //before
               //Call<ResponseTransaction> call =    transactionService.getFindAll(session_id);

                Call<ResponseTransaction> call = transactionService.getFindAll();
                call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseTransaction>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseTransaction> call, Response<ResponseTransaction> response) {
        // i think my problem in arround these line
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            ResponseTransaction responseTransaction = response.body();
                                if (responseTransaction.getSuccess().equals("true")) {
                                    transactionList = response.body().getResult();
                                        adapter = new TransactionAdapter(transactionList, getApplicationContext());
                                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                    }
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(TransationActivity.this, "DATA IS EMPTY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }





                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseTransaction> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(TransationActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

      }
```

This's code of Interfaces

```
public interface TransactionService {

 /*Before*/
 //@GET("transaction/findAll")
 // Call<ResponseTransaction> getFindAll(@Query("session_id") String      session_id);
 /*NOW*/
 @GET("transaction/findAll")
 Call<ResponseTransaction> getFindAll();
 }
```

This's a part My TransactionAdapter:

```
public class TransactionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TransactionAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Transaction> transactionList = new ArrayList();
    private Context context;

    public TransactionAdapter(List<Transaction> transactionList, Context context) {
        this.transactionList = transactionList;
        this.context = context;

    }


    @Override
    public TransactionAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.transaction_list, parent, false);
        TransactionAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new TransactionAdapter.ViewHolder(v, context, transactionList);
        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Transaction item = transactionList.get(position);
        holder.bind(item);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return transactionList.size();
    }


    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtId;
        TextView txtItem_code;
        TextView txtQty;
        TextView txtPrice;
        TextView txtTotal_price;
        TextView txtsessionID;


        private Transaction currentItem;
        Context context;
        ViewHolder(View itemView, Context context, List<Transaction> transactionList) {
            super(itemView);

            this.context = context;
            txtId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtId);
            txtId.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            txtsessionID = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtsessionID);
            txtsessionID.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            txtItem_code = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItem_code);
            txtQty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
            txtPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);

        }

        void bind(Transaction item) {

            txtId.setText(String.valueOf(item.getId()));
            txtsessionID.setText(String.valueOf(item.getSession_id()));

            txtItem_code.setText(item.getItem_code());
            txtQty.setText(String.valueOf(item.getQty()));

            txtPrice.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));

            currentItem = item;
        }

    }
```

This's a part of my API :

```
function findAll_get(){
               $infoLogin = $this->session->userdata('isLoggedIn');
               $sessiondt = $infoLogin;
               $this->load->model('M_transaction');
               $user_id = $sessiondt ['user_id'];
               $query   = $this->M_transaction->get_all($user_id);
                if($query){
                $this->response(['user_id'=>$user_id, 'success'=>true, 'result'=>$query ],REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
              }
              else
              {
              $this->response(['user_id'=>$user_id, 'success'=>false, 'result'=>'access disallowed'], REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
              }

        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your Adapter Class

Comment: Thanks @Md.Zakir Hosaain for your response. I updated my code

Comment: let me clear one thing. In your recylerView all other items show except user_id .Right?

Comment: @Md.ZakirHossain if after  success login ->activity transaction always displaying  "DATA IS EMPTY"

Comment: i want to display all data with user_id:74

Comment: your comment make me confused. Okay, if "DATA IS EMPTY"  is shown then you should check "response.isSuccessful()"  method. is isSuccessful() return boolean value? please debug your code and check "response.isSuccessful()" return which data?

Comment: in the table transaction alot of user_id has logged in and many data recorded  there example user_id :31,24 ect. and now in android application i want to filter it.

Comment: Please see it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012986/retrofit-post-request-response-issuccessful-returning-false

Comment: i think you should check your API which somehow doesn't return code 200.
Temporarily you can try this:
ResponseTransaction responseTransaction = response.body();
                                if (responseTransaction!=NULL && responseTransaction.getSuccess().equals("true")) {
                                    transactionList = response.body().getResult();
                                        //Your Code

                                    }

Comment: i tried your code but it doesn't works

Comment: Bro i updated my code there is $user_id = $sessiondt ['user_id']; if i  changed  $user_id='74'; then the resut is the data displaying and   filtered user_id=74

Comment: why if am i using the orignial code (using $user_id=$sessiondt['user_id']) in android it doesn't works?

Comment: @crazycoder  you `user_id` is Integer there is no way it will directly work by assigning it to string in hashmap, either convert your store type to Integer or parse integer to string and then store it.

Comment: Thanks @KaranMer for your response bro.i will be trying your response.

Comment: in postman when i execused The Above API with  user_id=$sessiondt['user_id']; or  $session_id=session_id(); and it session saved and as well as it works.